# PowerShell "There is an unexpected character in the query. "

Tags: powershell

I have a small PS ISE script that connects to the Exchange server, searches and deletes emails based on Subject line & exports results to Excel. The problem arises when I try to pass * as part of the subject line in the pop up window.

For example, if I want to delete all emails with subject line containing * MELATONIN * it fails. However, If I type the entire subject line without the * it works. But, my intent is to use the wildcard.

I understand that it sees the * as invalid. The question is How can I use it and prevent errors?
Any help will be appreciated.

```
cls
#checks for files existance and deletes them if found
$FileName = "C:\users\UserName\desktop\abc.csv"
If (Test-path $FileName) {
  Remove-Item $FileName }
  $FileName = "C:\users\UserName\desktop\abc2.csv"
If (Test-path $FileName) {
  Remove-Item $FileName }

#popup window to type email subject line to be deleted
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
$title = 'Subject Line'
$msg   = 'Enter subject line to search for:'
$text = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msg, $title)

#passing credentials thru script
$pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String "Password""
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "domain\UserName",$pw

#connecting to Exchange server   
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$ExSession =  New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 'http://EmailServer/PowerShell/' -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession ($ExSession) -AllowClobber

#running email search. HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR IF I USE *subject*
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | 
Search-mailbox -SearchQuery ([scriptblock]::create("Subject:'$text'")) -DeleteContent -force | 
Export-Csv c:\users\UserName\desktop\abc.csv -NoTypeInformation

start-sleep -s 2
#importing results and sorting parsing columns
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\abc.csv" |
  Select $Headers | 
  Select Identity, ResultItemsCount, ResultItemsSize |
  Sort ResultItemsCount -Descending |
 Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\abc2.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation

start-sleep -s 2
start "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\abc2.csv"

Remove-PSSession $ExSession
```

Comment: Have tried replacing the vb input box and attempted a direct partial string match within your script? e.g. ```$text = Read-host "enter the string"```

Comment: I rather a yes/no loop like this ```$YesNoResponse = $null
while ($YesNoResponse -ne "y" -and $YesNoResponse -ne "n") {
    Clear-Host
    write-host "Hit enter to break script. "  -ForegroundColor Magenta -NoNewline
    Write-Host "Run Something ?" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $YesNoResponse = Read-Host " [Y/N] "
    If ($YesNoResponse -eq "") {
        Return Write-Host "Enter was inputted" -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor White
    }
}```

Comment: maybe try a ```$text.trim()```  Or before your error, break and check your variables.
 I assume this works if you force the variable?

Comment: Have you tried `-SearchQuery "subject:*$text*"` ?

Comment: The **Search-Mailbox** cmdlet is being deprecated in favour of **New-ComplianceSearch** and related eDiscovery cmdlets.

Comment: `Get-MailboxServer | Where {$_.name -like '*MELATONIN*' }` Store the results of that into a variable and then use a foreach loop to loop them and do your `-DeleteContent` piece. Then you can use ConvertTo-CSV on your variable and output that to csv.

Comment: You should post the error you get to your question but this is clearly because `SearchQuery` is expecting a __search string__ or a __query formatted using Keyword Query Language (KQL)__ yet you're passing a `ScriptBlock` which is not supported.

Comment: -neothenerd,  Yes, I have. But it defeats my purpose. It is a lot easier to type a single word that to copy and paste the entire subject line. In addition some of the subject lines contain the recipient's email address so that would force me to literally run the script for every single email.

Comment: -dcaz, Yes, ive tried variations of * and using " and ' but they all have failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon This is the error.  There is an unexpected character in the query. Please re-type the query and try again. + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParserException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=ServerName,RequestId=1455c55f-8d93-4af0-8ad5-dbcb817a04bf,TimeStamp=12/7/2021 12:32:14 PM] [Fai 
   lureCategory=Cmdlet-ParserException] C32F15FC
    + PSComputerName        : ServerName

Comment: NeoTheNerd. New-ComplianceSearch is only available in Exchange 2016 and O365 center. Client is running Exchange 2013.

Comment: maybe this would help explain myself better:  this is the basic command I'm trying to run:   Search-mailbox -SearchQuery 'Subject:"*PartialSubjectLineHere*"' -DeleteContent -force .  The issue falls within the    'Subject:"*PartialSubjectLineHere*"' .  It is expecting a string and I'm not sure how to pass a variable to include asterisks as to only use a word and wild cards such as *Melatonin*.